# Add your own bash commands?

Tags: raspbian, bash

I wrote a programm in the c language, that I use all over the place, but every time I want to use it, I have to type out the whole path. **Can I add my script to the bash terminal?**

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/142215518744/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-2 and https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/142634263599/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store your program in one of the directories searched for commands (also referred to as the command path).

If you enter `echo $PATH` those directories will be listed.

I suggest you copy your executable to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo cp your-program /usr/local/bin
```

Make it executable (if you haven't already)

```
sudo chmod /usr/local/bin/your-program
```

You can then just type your-program to run your program.

Answer (score 2):

As per other answers, `$PATH` is the environment variable containing paths in which the shell looks for commands (see `echo $PATH`).  You want to either:

- Put the command or a link (see `man ln` and particularly the `-s` switch) into an element of path.  The standard place for this is `/usr/local/bin`, because:

  1. It usually takes precedence, i.e., is checked first, so you can override system commands this way.
  2. You won't have any conflicts with distro packages because they purposefully never install there.  You *could* have conflicts with source built packages (i.e., ones you build yourself) because they *usually* install there.

  Using a (symbolic) link looks something like this:

  ```
  ln -s /path/to/my/command /usr/bin/whatever-you-want-to-call-it
  ```

  Note the names do not have to match in any way.
- Add the location of the command to `$PATH`.  This allows you to have directories that are only used by particular users; a typical example is `$HOME/bin`, which may or may not be in `$PATH` already.  I'm using it as an example assuming it isn't.  First you create a `~/bin` directory, put your command or a link into it, and now the tricky part: Adding to `$PATH`.  This is best done per user, which is why I've described it that way, although it can be done system wide -- which I recommend avoiding for most people.

  The normal, old fashioned way to do this was adding a line like:

  ```
   PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
  ```

  to `~/.profile`, because traditionally that is sourced by *login* shells.  However, if you use a GUI login, particularly on Raspbian, you never use a login shell, so that file is never read.  Some people circumvent this by adding it to `~/.bashrc`, which is read by *every* shell invocation.  This is sort of a messy but probably not dangerous solution, since it may result in a `$PATH` which is duplicated many times.  For some solutions to that problem, see [this U&L Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124444/25985).

There are also various solutions to the `lightdm` issue (Raspbian's GUI login) scattered around, such as [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918649).

Answer (score 2):

Move your program to `~/bin`.

Raspbian (and Debian based distros) automatically add `$HOME/bin` to the `PATH` if that directory is present. You can check this in `~/.profile`:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Therefore, you can put your C programs in `~/bin`, and they'll work from anywhere while you're logged as that user. If you want other users to access it, use the system wide `PATH` for user programs: `/usr/local/bin`

Sources:

- [How to add /home/username/bin to $PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path)
- [Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local)

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a built in called "alias" to make you own bash commands. See "man alias"

Answer (score 0):

Programs developed in Linux are normally added to /usr/local/bin while software included in the distro is put in /usr/bin or /usr/sbin.  The difference is sbin normally requires root privileges.

Type `$PATH` at the terminal to see your system path and you'll see /usr/local/bin there showing it's one of the places the shell will look when you type in a program name.  When multiple users are developing on the same system it's not uncommon to add a /home/username/bin to their own path.  I normally add my scripts folder to my own path to have them quick at hand.

For example to add my own scripts directory to my path it would be `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts`if you want everyone to have access then put it in /usr/local/bin with the appropriate permissions.